# PYTHON: virtual method behavior differences for public, private(single underscore) and private(double underscore) methods

Tags: python, virtual-functions, private-methods

I was trying out NVI(Non-Virtual Interface) Idiom in python, and noticed that private(double underscore) methods don't seem to be acting as virtual.

```
class A(object):
    def a(self):
        print "in A.a"
    self.b()
    self.__b()
    self._b()

def _b(self):
    print "in A._b"

def __b(self):
    print "in A.__b"

def b(self):
    print "in A.b"

class B(A):
def __b(self):
    print "in B.__b"

def b(self):
    print "in B.b"

def _b(self):
    print "in B._b"

>>> a=A()
>>> b=B()
>>> a.a()
in A.a
in A.b
in A.__b
in A._b
>>> b.a()
in A.a
in B.b
in A.__b
in B._b
```

I am guessing this may have been because of name mangling for double underscore methods, but it is counter-intuitive. Further, confusion arises from python documentation "(For C++ programmers: all methods in Python are effectively virtual.)".

Comment: you should fix the code indentation, it is not clear what was your intent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references) says, double-leading-underscore methods are for **class-private members**.  They are private to the specific class in which they are used, not to its class inheritance subtree.  That is the point: they are designed for class-specific variables whose values you *don't* want subclass definitions to override, or subclass methods to access.

You are correct that the name-mangling is the source of the behavior you describe.  All Python methods are indeed virtual in that they can be overridden.  The double-underscore methods just make access from outside the class harder by mangling the name.  You could override `A.__b` by defining a method `_A__b` in class `B`.  That would be a bad idea because it would be subverting the purpose of using double-underscores in the first place, but it is possible.

Comment: Whether or not it's a bad idea is a matter of perspective ;-) -- As the idiom goes, "We're all consenting adults here".  But it certainly isn't something that should be done without a lot of thought.

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis is correct. This is due to name mangling, which effectively makes `A.__b` unrelated to `B.__b` (since they have different mangled names).